# Initialize Properties not initialized by Object Initializer

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I am writing some kind of driver for a device connected by a Serial Port. Before using the device, some settings have to be transmitted. For those I created properties, of which the setters send the settings to the device and also store the setting into a private variable, and the getters only return the private variable. So far so good. But I would also like to work with default values when these properties do not get initialized before starting using the device.

That's why I would like to execute some code directly after the initializations by object initializator. So that I only initialize those settings with default value that hasn't been initialized yet. And I do not want to do it by a function that has to be called from outside.

Is there any way to reach this?

Comment: "*of which the setters send the settings to the device*" -- please don't do this. Property getters/setters shouldn't be doing things like I/O, or other things which take an amount of time or might randomly fail. Use a method.

Comment: No, there is no way to automatically execute a method once an object initializer has finished.

Comment: instead of providing your default-values **after** the rest was done, why not do it **before**? Then everything that has not been explictely set stays default, and everything else gets overwritten.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!
@canton7 You are right, with my way that is comfortable to use, I probably don't fullfil expectations of others that will use my code in future. I think will convert my properties into tuples so that they can store the information if they are already transmitted, but I will transmit in an function.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That is the way I am actually doing, but it means that some settings are set two times. Which is not a serious problem since I dont have timing constraints, but I dont like it.